# Archiving Old Issues in JIRA

Tags: jira, archive

Is it possible to archive issues which are older than a specific date. The issue may belong to any project and the status must be closed.

I would define archiving as deleting it completely from the live instance and store them in some format so that they can be referred if needed.

Comment: Atlassian does not yet support this but it is a highly voted issue. See [JRA-5843](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-5843) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Atlasian's [Archiving a Project](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Archiving+a+Project), especially check:

- [Archiving a project offline](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Archiving+a+Project#ArchivingaProject-Archivingaprojectoffline)- create a global XML backup and delete the project.
- [Accessing an archived offline project](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Archiving+a+Project#ArchivingaProject-Accessinganarchivedofflineproject)- restore the project to Jira test instance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool I made for my needs which basically allows to convert Jira project to html website for archiving purposes - maybe it will be useful for you: https://gitlab.com/kaszaq/jiratomkdocs/